# Can we read SQL results as is into a variable instead of string

Tags: java, arrays, date, arraylist

I have two database - SRC and TGT having table TAB1. I need to verify that the data in both tables is same. The table has data set of types int, varchar, date etc..
When I read the result set in to arraylist, its converted to string. Because of this my comparison failing due to the fact that DATE columns in both SRC and TGT tables are yielding different formats as they are converted to string. 
My SQL and results are as below:

Select * from TAB1:

```
Sl No | Name | DOB        | Age | Salary
1     | ABC  | 09/02/2000 | 18  | 100.20
2     | XYZ  | 02/02/2000 | 18  | 200.40
```

We are using below piece of java code:

```
Statement stmt = databaseDBconn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from TAB1");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetadata();
int colnum = rsmd.getColumnCount();
String[] str = new string[colnum];

while (rs.next()) {
    for (int i=1;i<=colnum;i++) {
        str[i-1] = rs.getstring(i);
        tablearray.table1.add(str[i-1]);
    }
}
```

we have used same above code for TAB1 in both SRC and TGT database. 
Even though the data in both tables is same, we are getting error message because of the DATE column value is getting converted to string.

Is there a way we can have DATE as is without getting this converted to string for comparison?

Comment: Have you considered `ResultSet`'s four versions of the `getDate()` method?  Alternatively, `getObject()` ought to give you a `java.sql.Date` (probably) or `java.sql.Timestamp` (maybe), too, when the SQL column type is `DATE`.

Comment: It's converted into a string because you tell it to be converted to a string (`getstring`). If you don't want that behavior, then do not implement it[.](http://roboter-basteln.de/)

Comment: @JohnBollinger The two-arg `getObject` methods will give you a `java.time.LocalDate` when you ask them to, freeing you from the outdated `Date` and `Timestamp` classes.

Comment: By the way, you might find a database migration tool to be useful in keeping your database structures intact, such as [*FlyWay*](http://www.FlywayDB.com/) or *LiquiBase*.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
while(rs.next) {
  int slNo = rs.getInt("Sl No");
  String name = rs.getString("Name");
  Date dob = rs.getDate("DOB");
  int age = rs.getInt("Age);
  BigDecimal salary = new BigDecimal(row.getString("Salary"));
}
```

That way each column is stored in an appropriate datatype.

Comment: Correct answer, but the `Date` class is long outdated. Better: `LocalDate dob = rs.getObject("DOB", LocalDate.class);` (using `java.time`, just requires a JDBC 4.2 compliant driver, which you’re likely to have already and can get if not).

Comment: Right, I still maintain a Java 6 project when I use the JDBC stuff, I'm out of date!

Comment: @Matt For Java 6 & 7, use the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, back-porting much of the *java.time* functionality. Virtually the same API. Later, when you move to Java 8 or 9 or later, you’ll need do little more than change your `import` statements. In the back-port, you can convert between legacy and modern classes via the [`DateTimeUtils`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html) class, in Java 8 and later use new conversion methods added to the legacy classes.